# Unknown primary key for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, refinerycms

I'm making an extension for refinerycms in rails and this is the structure I follow :

Project has many project_images
Project_images belongs_to Project & Image ( The refinery Image class )

Now when I want to create a new object of ProjectImage in my Project class I always get this error :

```
Unknown primary key for table refinery_projects_images in model Refinery::Projects::ProjectImage.
```

I don't need a primary key for this table because it is a join table. Here is the code of my models and migration file:

Migration.rb

```
class CreateProjectsProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    create_table :refinery_projects do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :investor
      t.string :location
      t.string :area
      t.string :purpose
      t.string :architect
      t.string :users
      t.integer :position
      t.integer :position

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :refinery_projects, :id

    create_table :refinery_projects_images, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :image
      t.references :project
      t.integer :position
      t.string :category
      t.string :caption
    end

    add_index :refinery_projects_images, [:image_id, :project_id], :uniq => true

  end

  def down
    if defined?(::Refinery::UserPlugin)
      ::Refinery::UserPlugin.destroy_all({:name => "refinerycms-projects"})
    end

    if defined?(::Refinery::Page)
      ::Refinery::Page.delete_all({:link_url => "/projects/projects"})
    end

    drop_table :refinery_projects
    drop_table :refinery_projects_images

  end

end
```

Project.rb

```
module Refinery
  module Projects
    class Project < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      self.table_name = 'refinery_projects'

      attr_accessible :title, :description, :investor, :location, :area, :purpose, :architect, :users, :position, :position, :images_attributes

      acts_as_indexed :fields => [:title, :description, :investor, :location, :area, :purpose, :architect, :users]

      validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

      has_many :project_images
      has_many :images, :through => :project_images, :order => 'position ASC'

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => false

      def images_attributes=(data)
        ProjectImage.delete_all(:project_id => self.id)

        (0..(data.length-1)).each do |i|
          unless (image_data = data[i.to_s]).nil? or image_data['id'].blank?
            project_image = self.project_images.new(:image_id => image_data['id'].to_i, :position => i)
            # Add caption if supported
            if false
              project_image.caption = image_data['caption']
            end
            self.project_images << project_image
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

ProjectImage.rb

```
module Refinery
  module Projects
    class ProjectImage < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      self.table_name = 'refinery_projects_images'

      attr_accessible :image_id, :position

      belongs_to :image, :class_name => 'Refinery::Image'
      belongs_to :project, :class_name => 'Refinery::Projects::Project'
    end
  end
end
```

Somebody knows why he keeps looking for the primary key?

Answer (score 2):

Refinery::Core::BaseModel is somehow derived from ActiveRecord::Base. When you use that class then your table layout needs an id. If you don't want an id, Have a look at `has_and_belongs_to_many` in the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Ok in the doc there is also mentioned this "Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many", I use the has_many through so this means it should also work? The fact is that I don't have access to the Image Class from refinery to add  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

Comment: Can you not just (Ruby-style) reopen the class and add your association?

Comment: ok, but if you look good to my question you see that the projects_images table contains more then just the joining attributes. Regarding to the rails doc they advise me to use has_many through => "You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model." Like mentioned in my question I need position, category and caption attributes

Comment: Exactly, but for this you need an ActiveRecord model in between and this in turn asks for a table with an id. The reason is that for example Model.find couldn't work without it.